# How to skip a footnote at the end of csv file using CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to read a CSV file in the form of:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 12/1/2020 | 1 |
| 12/2/2020 | 2 |

At the end of the file is a footnote which is all text.

If I use:

```
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

CsvHelper throws, "FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."

It will work if I use:

```
while (csv.Read()) {
   try {
        records.Add(csv.GetRecord<Foo>());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

but that is really slow.

I was hoping that adding:

```
csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = record => record.Contains("The");
```

would solve the problem, but I get the same error.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. (My apologies for not being able to format the table correctly.)

Comment: Is the footnote one line and does it start with "The"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the footnote is only the text `The`, then what you have would work. To do what you're trying to do, you'd need to do something like this:

```cs
csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = record => record.FirstOrDefault()?.StartsWith("The") ?? false;
```

You could test if there is only 1 (or less) fields too.

```cs
csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = record => record.Count() <= 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Josh.  I was really intrigued by your last suggestion, because it would apply to any footnote (as long as there wasn't a comma in the footnote).  Unfortunately, when I looked at my csv files in Notepad, rather than Excel, I see that each line is followed by the required number of commas, so that won't work.  Rather than hard coding what to skip, is it possible to skip any record that does not start with a number?  I tried csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = record => !record.FirstOrDefault()?.StartsWith("0") & !record.FirstOrDefault()?.StartsWith("1") ?? false;

Comment: `csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = record => Regex.IsMatch(record.FirstOrDefault(), "[0-9].+]");`

Answer (score 0):

You could define the character used to denote a commented line:

```
var configuration = new CsvConfiguration { AllowComments = true, Comment = '#' };
using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"), configuration))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
}
```

But this requires that you can manipulate the csv file or that the first character of the last line is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV is large, ShouldSkipRecord can increase the time to process by 10-20x even with the most basic record.Length check.

@dontbyteme's solution gave me an idea. Just set the comment character to the letter T. This should not impact performance and give you the desired result.

```
var configuration = new CsvConfiguration { AllowComments = true, Comment = 'T' };
using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"), configuration))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
}
```